# Detecting bad antenna vs bad ssid/password with dhclient/ifconfig

Tags: networking, wifi, ifconfig

I'm working on an embedded device that I think has a bad wifi antenna.

When I start the device I run `ifconfig` and see the wifi interface:

```
...
wlan3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ea:40:d7:63:27  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I then make a wifi access point on my laptop with no password. I try to set the device to use it with `iwconfig wlan3 essid philip`.

Then I assign the interface an IP with `dhclient wlan3 -v`, the logs from verbose seem to indicate it was a success. Also I run `ifconfig` again and can see my interface has an IP:

```
...
wlan3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:ea:40:d7:63:27  
          inet addr:192.168.12.120  Bcast:192.168.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::aea:40ff:fed7:6327/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:34 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1846 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:7274 (7.2 KB)
```

Though I know in practicality I'm not connected because running `ping -I wlan3 -c 1 8.8.8.8` fails.

1. Does the assignment of an IP confirm that my wifi did connect to the network? *(with an incorrect password or ssid `dhclient wlan3` seems to just hang)*
2. Can I infer anything about a potential hardware problem from the `RX` and `TX` values in the second `ifconfig`?

*End goal is to have my software tell the difference between an incorrect ssid/password and faulty hardware.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes.

2) No.

`iw wlan3 station dump` may give you better information to detect potential hardware problems, i.e. a missing or bad antenna.

3) If the problem is to detect an incorrect SSID or Password, and assuming you are (indirectly) using `wpa_supplicant` (and not WEP or no encryption), have a look at `wpa_cli`.

Comment: For any future readers. I also found just running `iwconfig` will return the interface with info about if it is associated.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride: "Associated" only means it has found an AP with this SSID, you still need `wpa_supplicant` to check authentication status (password). You can also use `iw dev wlan3 scan` to check for available SSIDs.